# Open a file from `My Documents` on Windows

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I'm writing plugins for sketch up. I cannot find a simple way to append a text file from the `My Documents` directory on Windows. The problems I am having are:

- opening with the current username
- differences between Windows versions.

I need the code to open a file in append mode in `My Documents` on Windows 7 on a 32bit machine.

Comment: I mean open a file in append mode - sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file = File.open(ENV['userprofile'] + "\\My Documents\\file.txt", "a")
file.puts "text to append"
file.close
```

---

**EDIT:**
[Default location of user's documents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Folders#File_system_directories)  is:

**On Windows 98 and Windows Me**
`C:\My Documents`
**On Windows 2000 and Windows XP**
`%USERPROFILE%\My Documents`
**On Windows Vista and later**
`%USERPROFILE%\Documents`

> **Non-English** versions of **Windows XP** or **earlier** will use directory names
>   appropriate to that language.

[You can find the right path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3492996/1136008) on Non-English systems in Windows Registry:

```
require 'win32/registry'
reg_path = 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders'
reg = Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER.open( reg_path )
right_path = reg['Personal']    # => C:\Documents and Settings\addo\Dokumenty
```

Comment: Although this method does work, it does not open files from a particular directory. On windows, this is not particularly efficient. Thanks anyway though

Comment: oh totally forgot you were asking something more specific ;) I'll try to update.

Comment: Should actually be `ENV['userprofile'] + '/My Documents/file.txt'`

Comment: Constants in Ruby begins with a capital letter. And constants should be constant :) Rename `Current_file` to `current_file`.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell you are right, he wanted 'my documents', but I would avoid this because not everyone use EN Windows.. f.e. I have `Dokumenty`. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/3492996/1136008

Comment: @A.D. I was merely referring to the original question. I also do not use "My Documents".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the backtick ` in Ruby to run a command line against the system. It will then return the result of the call.

Here's the official description at [Ruby-Doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-60)

> Returns the standard output of running cmd in a subshell. The built-in
>   syntax %x{...} uses this method. Sets $? to the process status.

```
`echo` #=> 'ECHO is on.' if ran on Windows
```

In Windows, there are [special variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) you can use to gather information such as a username:

```
echo %username%
```

Hence, you can use these two to gather the location of the user's My Documents folder (provided they are on Windows).

```
# Tested on Windows XP and 7
my_documents = File.join(`echo %userprofile%`.chomp, "My Documents")
```

**Note:**
There is also a method in Ruby that makes system calls which is [`system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system). However, this returns a boolean which will not work in your case.

Also note that this solution will **only** work on Windows.