# Can a .bat be used to delete files across multiple machines in a network?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, delete-file

I am trying to find a way of deleting selected files/folders on Windows 7 machines attached to my local network.

The problem I have is that the location of ''my Documents'' is different on ALL machines as in Windows 7 the path = C:\Users**username**\Documents.

I would like to place a batch file in a shared directory so it can be run locally on machines at the required time.

Any help or advice is most appreciated.

Comment: Where are the files you want to delete? Why is it a Problem that the "my documents" Folders are different?

Comment: Hi Werner,
The folders are located within ''My Documents''
And it is a problem because I want to have a single batch file that can be used by each machine, run manually, locally.
Please tell me if I am being naive and missing something obvious here?.?.? Is there an easier option other than using a batch file? Or is there script that conquers this problem?

Comment: So "my documents" resides on a Network drive? It would be nice if you wrote your question more clearly.

Comment: No ''My Documents'' is a local library on the Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be quite simple if the 'My Documents' folder were named the same in all Windows operating systems with environment variables: `%USERPROFILE%` always points to the user's folder, and `"%USERPROFILE%\My Documents"` would do it. Unfortunately in Windows XP, it is named `My Documents` and in Windows Vista and 7, it is named `Documents`. If all the computers you mentioned name My Documents as the same name, this can be used.

There *is* a way out without checking for the Windows operating system though, but it requires administrative access. I got this from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492920/is-there-a-system-defined-environment-variable-for-documents-directory) on Stack Overflow that it can be found in the registry at `"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"` under `Personal`. `reg query` will find the value and this can be extracted with a `for` loop:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2* delims= " %%g in (`reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v Personal') do set "documents=%%i"

echo %documents%
del "%documents%\etc"
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively, you could also search for the presence of a `Documents` folder, though this might get thrown off by a `Documents` folder that may exist in someone's Windows XP user profile directory, for example.

```
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" (
    del "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\etc"
) else (
    del "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\etc"
)
```

**EDIT 2:** To delete all files and subfolders in My Documents (if the name is called `My Documents`) but not the folder itself, use this:

```
del "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\*"
for /d %%i in ("%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\*") do rd /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\%%i"
```

(first one is to delete all files and second one for all subfolders)

**EDIT 3:** To do the finding out if `Documents` exist and delete all:

```
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" (
    rd /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Documents"
    md "%USERPROFILE%\Documents"
) else (
    rd /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents"
    md "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents"
)
```

`/s` is to delete all files and subfolders, and `/q` is for quiet mode where they will not prompt you whether to delete anything. Then `md` to make the folder again.

Comment: Thanks guys
So, If the user had a folder called ''johnsmith'' in the ''Documents'' library and I wanted to delete the entire contents of that folder, what should my batch file look like?

Comment: Which method do you want to use?

Comment: i think using the %USERPROFILE% command would be easiest..

Comment: You should only use it if all the computers have the `My Documents` directory named as the same name.. Are they?

Comment: Yes. They all have the deafult ''My Documents'' Folder

Comment: I have added the code above. Sorry for the slow response, my internet connection is intermittently cutting off.

Comment: I wrote this code :
@echo off
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" (
   del "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\"/F /Q
) else (
   del "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\"/F /Q
)

And it works to delete all files. What do I add and where to delete folders?

Sorry for my ignorance... Bit of a Newbie

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a bat file that works for different users and deletes files from the user's "my documents" folder, then you can write a bat file with a command like that:

```
del %USERPROFILE%\Documents\file_to_delete
rd /qs %USERPROFILE%\Documents\folder_to_delete
```

Windows sets the variable USERPROFILE to the right Location for each user. You can check the value of USERPROFILE and other environment variables in cmd.exe with

```
set
```